# Can MySQL list a column before * in a SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I can get any SELECT statement that has '*' plus some other facet like a CASE statement or whatever in my SELECT clause to work if I always put '*' first.  So, this works:

```
SELECT *, (@row_number := @row_number + 1) AS num
FROM tblContracts, (SELECT @row_number := 0) as T;
```

But this does not:

```
SELECT (@row_number := @row_number + 1) AS num, *
FROM tblContracts, (SELECT @row_number := 0) as T;
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong here, or is this some quirk of MySQL?  This is really my first exposure to MySQL.

Comment: I would always use a table alias anyway.  I know the second syntax doesn't work in Oracle.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question.

Comment: Maybe I have answered my own question.  I didn't know if I was missing some weird syntax thing with MySQL.  I don't see a good reason for it not to work, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The * needs qualifying with the table name

```
SELECT (@row_number := @row_number + 1) AS num, tblContracts.*
FROM tblContracts, (SELECT @row_number := 0) as T;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good practice to alias your tablename. Also, anytime you have a `select *` following where other columns are selected explicitly, you need to define where the  `*` is coming from:

```
SELECT (@row_number := @row_number + 1) AS num, tc.*
FROM tblContracts tc, (SELECT @row_number := 0) as T;
```

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703901/can-mysql-list-a-column-before-in-a-select) is not explicit about when you can and cannot use `*` with other columns.  But, it does say:

> - Use of an unqualified `*` with other items in the select list may produce a parse error. To avoid this problem, use a qualified
>     `tbl_name.*` reference
>
>   SELECT AVG(score), t1.* FROM t1 ...

Of course, the example given in the documentation just perpetuates an even worse problem, which is having unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` of an aggregation query.

But, the advice about qualifying column names and `*` is good advice.  It would seem that your example is an example of a parse failure.  Using table aliases is recommended, even without the parse failure.